# MongoDB JSON array within JSON object field removal

Tags: java, android, mongodb

I have a json object as following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("508806803bb97dc546e6f307"), "user_name" : "user1", "user_id" : 45645645, "likes" : [ { "event_id" : NumberLong("4578541212") },{ "event_id" : NumberLong("4578541213") } ], "dislikes" : [ ] }
```

I'm trying to delete specific event within likes array via java drivers
tried doing this first in shell:

```
> db.users.update( {'likes.event_id' : 4578541212}, { '$unset':{'likes.event_id'
:1}})
```

with no luck...how can I manage doing that?

Comment: Do you want to remove the `event_id` field from the array element (leaving an empty element) or remove the element itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just remove the `event_id` field from the array element:

```
db.users.update( {'likes.event_id' : 4578541212}, {'$unset':{'likes.$.event_id' :1}})
```

Use the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) operator to delete the element:

```
db.users.update({'likes.event_id': 4578541212}, {'$pull':{likes: {event_id: 4578541212}}})
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked, but I have another question:
as I executed the command you suggested the whole record was messed up (fields switch places), any idea why is this happning?